# Migrating ObjC NSNumber code to Swift and having problems with displaying numbers.

Tags: ios, swift

I am migrating my ObjC app to Swift and have run into a peculiar issue.

My app reads a JSON file and builds a model from it. The numbers read from JSON used to be assigned to NSNumber. Some numbers were whole (eg.60) other had a decimal component (e.g. 60.23).

When I displayed these numbers in my app, 60 would be 60 (not 60.0) and decimals would display appropriately.

Now I am writing Swift code and assigning the numbers read from JSON to Double. Even if I use let x=String(myDouble) the number 60 will always come out 60.0

I don't want this...but I can't just format it %f because I never know if the number will be whole or have a decimal component.

Do I really need to check if it is a whole and then format it using it %f?

Am I missing something in Swift? The ObjC code behaved as I wanted by now Swift seems to be giving me decimals for whole numbers.

Comment: If you want NSNumber's behaviour, why switch to Double?

Comment: To be honest I only used NSNumber because it was easier passing it around in ObjC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `NSNumberFormatter`.

```
let number1 : Double = 60
let number2 = 60.23

let numberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.numberStyle = .DecimalStyle
let number1String = numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(number1) // "60"
let number2String = numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(number2) // "60.23"
```

Comment: You can also set the minimum and maximum number of fraction digits to further customize the display. Another benefit of using the formatter is that the decimal separator is correctly localized.

Comment: And the number formatter should be cached and reused as its creation is somewhat costly.

Comment: This might work for me. I will give it a try. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, here is the code in PlayGround:

```
let number = 60.23
String(number)

let double:Double = 60

//First way
String(NSNumberFormatter().stringFromNumber(double)!)


//Second way
let doubleString = String(double)

if doubleString.containsString(".0") {
    let length = doubleString.characters.count

    let index = doubleString.characters.indexOf(".")
    doubleString.substringToIndex(index!)
}
```

[image]

Comment: In this example how are you sure the first number is not being cast as an int?